# How can I draw this shape in mathematica?

Tags: graphics

How can I draw this shape in Mathematica? It's a circle with a number of equidistant points on it and spikes perpendicular to the circle.

[image]

Comment: `pts=CirclePoints[16];Graphics [{PointSize[.02],Circle[],Point[pts],Line/@Thread[{pts,.6 pts}]}]`

Comment: And you can control the placement with the form `pts = CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, 16];`

Comment: Do you mean  tremble drawing?

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on @martin's answer

```
pts = CirclePoints[16];
g1 = Graphics[{PointSize[.02], Circle[], Point[pts]}];
g2 = Graphics[Line /@ Thread[{pts, .6 pts}]];

Overlay[{ResourceFunction["XKCDConvert"][g2, "Distortion" -> 3], g1}]
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using ? the xkcd lines do not fit on top of the dots on my computer in Linux version 13.1. Ah it is because the resource function outputs an image and there is an issue between graphics and images since version 12.1

Comment: @userrandrand I am using "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)".

Comment: Thanks not sure why the overlay did not work with me then. I might keep in mind that possibility to use `Overlay` sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** included random orientation and scaling of the wavy lines.

Using @RohitNamjoshi's idea to use the xkcd resource function and @martin's initial code we can include the squiggly lines on the circle using Bezier curves with random points and randomly shift and scale the inner points that the wavy lines attach to;

```
pts = CirclePoints[16];
squiggly = BezierCurve[RandomPoint[Disk[#, 0.05], 20]] & /@ pts;
g1 = Graphics[{squiggly, Circle[]}];
shifted = 
  RandomReal[0.6 + 0.1*{-1, 1}]*# + 0.1*RandomReal[] & /@ pts;
g2 = Graphics[Line /@ Thread[{pts, shifted}]];
wavy = ResourceFunction["XKCDConvert"][g2, "Distortion" -> 3];
```

Overlay did not work with me on Linux 13.1 probably because of the resolution bug that was introduced since 12.1 which makes it difficult to find a correspondence between graphics and images. My workaround here was to use [`HighlightImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightImage.html):

```
HighlightImage[wavy, {Black, ColorNegate@Image@g1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does someone know what to do to get images and graphics to work better together since the bug that was introduced ? I saw an answer that uses ImageResolution->72 or something but if I remember well that did not work for me when I wanted to use a Graphics object as a mask in an image. I also so not know how to overlay an image on a graphics after using `ImageGraphics`. Finally, `HighlightImage` is not perfect there is still some lines that cross the circle there.